# How to handle null exceptions in Razor Conditionals

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
        <div class="display-label">
            <a>Contact</a>
            @(Model.Store.EmployeeType.Name == "Manager" ? Model.Store.HQ.Manager.DisplayName : Model.Store.Manager.DisplayName )
        </div>
```

How should null exceptions for each of these Entities be handled in the view?  I have a TON of these kind of  - is there an elegant way to check for nulls without doing an if statement before each one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a property on your ViewModel:

```
public class ManagerViewModel 
{
    public string Manager {get;set;}
}
```

And in your controller:

```
var viewModel = new ManagerViewModel();
viewModel.Manager = Model.Store.EmployeeType.Name == "Manager" ? Model.Store.HQ.Manager.DisplayName : Model.Store.Manager.DisplayName;
return View(viewModel);
```

Then in your view, all you need to do is:

```
@Model.Manager
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  What if EmployeeType.Name is null in your case?  Will the view still render?

Comment: And - doesn't this violate the skinny controller best practice?  I have about 30 fields that need this type of filtering.  Is it better to have a fat controller than a fat view?

Comment: if the `EmployeeType.Name` is `null`, it'll still render since string is already nullable. As for the skinny controller bit, take a look at my answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515512/124069).