# Moving logic from View to Controller and ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm moving all definitions like the following:

```
 @(Model.Store.EmployeeType.Name == "Manager" ? Model.Store.HQ.Manager.DisplayName : Model.Store.Manager.DisplayName )
```

Out of my View and into a viewModel:

```
public class ManagerViewModel 
{
    public string Manager {get;set;}
}
```

And defining them in the controller:

```
var viewModel = new ManagerViewModel();

viewModel.Manager = Model.Store.EmployeeType.Name == "Manager" ? Model.Store.HQ.Manager.DisplayName : Model.Store.Manager.DisplayName;

return View(viewModel);
```

Now, in my View I can do this:

```
@Model.Manager
```

My question is - does this violate the skinny controller best practice?  I have about 30 fields that need this type of treatment, so my controller is going to be pretty big -  I'm creating a new property for every field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry too much about [premature optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385529/124069). I think you're on the right path here and wouldn't worry too much about it.

You could populate the ViewModel from within the Constructor if you're really worried about "skinny" controllers.

```
public class ManagerViewModel 
{

    public ManagerViewModel(ManagerModel model){
        // initialize in here
        this.Manager = model.Store.EmployeeType.Name == "Manager" ? model.Store.HQ.Manager.DisplayName : model.Store.Manager.DisplayName;
    }

    public string Manager {get;set;}
}
```

```
var viewModel = new ManagerViewModel(model);
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks Chase.  How would this change if I was working on a Details page?  If I initialize everything within the viewModel, where would the  "var manager = db.Managers.Find(id);" go?

Comment: Every View should have it's own ViewModel. Therefore you'll need a `ManagersViewModel`(list of managers) and a `ManagerViewModel`(details for a single manager.)

Comment: ps: I was assuming that your current `ManagerViewModel` IS a details View. If it's not, please elaborate on what it IS.

Comment: It is a Details view.  With the ManagerViewModel(model), are you passing "manager" from my previous comment to the ViewModel, as "model"?